# Get correct parameter value from URL in "/:id=" format using regex

Tags: ios, swift, regex

What is the best way to get the id value from this url:

```
URL(string: "urlScheme://search/:id=0001")
```

I've been trying to route this URL using a deep link request. However, my url routing solution JLRoutes shows the parameters as key = id and value = :id=0001.

I instead need the parameters to be key = id and value = "0001".

In an ideal world I would just be using a URL string like "urlScheme://search/0001" and not have any problem but the "**:id=**" part has to be in there. George's comment about converting the parameter to a URL in of itself and using **.pathComponents.last** does work, but I think a regex solution is probably going to scale better going forward.

Comment: What about regex?

Comment: I just a need a native swift solution.

Comment: ... or just treat as a string and split on '/'.   Or use `.pathComponents.last` and interpret manually?  There's many ways to go about this

Comment: @flanker Btw you can do `lastPathComponent`

Comment: swift supports regex natively in String's `.range(of: "searchString", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: @George Thanks.  Had forgotten all about that :)

Comment: @denvdancsk Are you meant to have your URL as `urlScheme://search?id=0001` instead, so it's an actual query?

Comment: @George no. The way the url looks now is how it looks

Comment: @flanker I think I may have to come up with a regex solution. I'm not very good at regex. So let me update the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @George should work fine,  but two things struck me:  you decided you wanted a regex solution, and to make this generic seemed to be asking for a recursive solution.

The below approach uses regex to identify up to the last `/:` delimiter, then has to do a bit of inelegant string handling to split it into the base string and the final pair of (key: value) params.  I'd hoped to be able to write a regex that just matches those final parameters as that would be a far cleaner range to work with, but haven't managed it yet!

```
func paramsFrom(_ str: String) -> [String: String] {
   guard let baseRange = str.range(of:#"^.+\/:"#, options: .regularExpression ) else { return [:] }
   let base = String(str[baseRange].dropLast(2))
   let params = str.replacingCharacters(in: baseRange, with: "").components(separatedBy: "=")
   return [params.first! : params.last!].merging(paramsFrom(base)){(current, _) in current}
}
```

using this on your example string returns:

```
["id": "0001", "title": "256", "count": "100"]
```

---

EDIT:

Managed to dig out the old regex brain cells and match just the final pair of parameters.  You could adapt the above to use the regex

```
(?<=\/:)[a-zA-Z0-9=]+$
```

and the have slightly cleaner string handling as the shortened base string becomes

```
String(str.dropLast(str[paramsRange].count))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your URL is in the form of an actual URL query, e.g. `urlScheme://search?id=0001`, there is a nice way to do this.

With thanks to [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian), this is really simple. You can just do the following:

```
let components = URLComponents(string: "urlScheme://search?id=0001&a=2")!

let dict = components.queryItems?.reduce(into: [:]) { partialResult, queryItem in
    partialResult[queryItem.name] = queryItem.value
}
```

Or a slightly more compact version for `dict`:

```
let dict = components.queryItems?.reduce(into: [:], { $0[$1.name] = $1.value })
```

Result from given input:

> ```
> ["id": "0001", "a": "2"]
> ```

---

#### If you must use the current URL form

You can replace the URL string, such as:

```
let urlStr = "urlScheme://search/:id=0001/:a=2"
let comps = urlStr.components(separatedBy: "/:")

let newUrl: String

if comps.count > 1 {
    newUrl = "\(comps.first!)?\(comps.dropFirst().joined(separator: "&"))"
} else {
    newUrl = urlStr
}

print(newUrl)
```

Prints: `urlScheme://search?id=0001&a=2`

---

#### Original answer (slightly modified)

If you have a URL with queries separated by `/:` you can use the following:

```
// Example with multiple queries
let url = URL(string: "urlScheme://search/:id=0001/:a=2")!

let queries = url.lastPathComponent.dropFirst().split(separator: "/:")
var dict = [String: String]()

for query in queries {
    let splitQuery = query.split(separator: "=")
    guard splitQuery.count == 2 else { continue }
    let key = String(splitQuery.first!)
    let value = String(splitQuery[1])
    dict[key] = value
}

print(dict)
```

Result is same as before.

Comment: There is a much more convenient API: `let components = URLComponents(string: "urlScheme://search?id=0001&a=2")!` `let dict = components.queryItems?.reduce(into: [:], {$0[$1.name] = $1.value})`

Comment: @vadian Wow, that is way better!

Comment: Unfortunately my URL isn't formatted with a traditional query, so this won't work.

Comment: @denvdancsk See the last part of the answer, where it will work for your current query style. If that’s still not suitable, check the code in the previous edit.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't scale because I may have multiple parameters. The URL in the question is just an example, but I will also have URLs like: "urlScheme://search/:id=0001/:title=256/:count=100"

Comment: @denvdancsk See the edit. The code is from the original edit, but with the separator character `&` changed to `/:`. However the best solution here is to replace all but the first of `/:` with `&`. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: @denvdancsk Ok, I've now edited the "If you must use the current URL form" section. I recommend you do that to change the URL, then use the `URLComponents` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next regex approach to enumerate parameters in your url path:

```swift
let urlString = "urlScheme://search/:id=0001" as NSString
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([^:\\/]+)=([0-9]+)")
if let match = regex.matches(in: urlString as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, urlString.length)).first, match.numberOfRanges == 3 {
    let key = urlString.substring(with: match.range(at: 1))
    let value = urlString.substring(with: match.range(at: 2))
    print(key, ":", value)
}

// Prints
id : 0001
```